# grep find the words with same vowels in a line

Tags: regex, grep

Given a txt file, how can I use grep to find the line that contains at least 5 times a same vowel using regular expression?

I tried:

```
egrep '[aeiou]{5,}\1' file
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Do you want to find the **line** that contains at least 5 times a same vowel or find **words** with at least 5 times a same vowel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to match for *a* vowel followed by `anything` and expect this pattern at least 5 times. So, for `a` alone, that would be:

```
egrep '(a.*){5,}' $FILE
```

Repeat that for each vowel using the `|` character, like:

```
egrep '(a.*){5,}|(e.*){5,} <and so on>' $FILE
```

There might be a better solution, for example compacting all those pipes (`|`), but I cannot think of any right now.

Answer (score 2):

For a test file that looks like this

```
aeiou
a1a2a3a4a5
e1e2e3e4e5
aaa
```

where we want to match the second and third line, you can use

```
$ grep -E '([aeiou]).*(\1.*){4}' infile 
a1a2a3a4a5
e1e2e3e4e5
```

This matches and captures any one vowel, then looks for four times the same vowel, padded with optional characters.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

To find words with at least 5 times the same vowel:

```
grep -Eo '\b\w*((a\w*){5,}|(e\w*){5,}|(i\w*){5,}|(o\w*){5,}|(u\w*){5,})\b' file
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)